# Problems with Fancybox and jQuery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Beating my head blue on this one. The fancybox won't trigger on the preview images below.
Everything is set according to manual.

http://www.itrosa.se/sv/Utstaellning_i_Trosa_kvarn/article/?i=s7486578460425622

any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting a *lot* javascript and validation errors (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.itrosa.se/sv/Utstaellning_i_Trosa_kvarn/article/%3Fi%3Ds7486578460425622&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0)...make sure to fix those otherwise you can't really get to the problem, this is currently throwing an error, take a look at your console: `jQuery("textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander();`

Answer (score 0):

You have a JS error:

Error: jQuery("textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander is not a function
Source File: http://www.itrosa.se/pub/SYSTEM/jquery.textarea-expander.js
Line: 94

And, according to my firebug, $(document).ready() is not called.
Maybe you have to look into these two issues...

Comment: that textarea thing was irrelevant. "Result of expression '$("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox' [undefined] is not a function." is the issue

Comment: @Fredrik: JavaScript is single threaded, no error is irrelevant, any error can cause trouble down the road.

Answer (score 0):

remove slideShow(); from the document.ready section like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'titlePosition'     : 'over',
            'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You probably just carried over some code from your slideshow script or incorporated it with the fancybox script incorrectly.